# Typo3 Create footer for form

Tags: php, forms, typo3, typoscript

I'm quite new to typo3 so I'm sorry if I'm missing the obvious.

I want to render text undderneath the submit button of a form.

Just adding an element after the form sadly isn't an option.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The simplest way is just to add a check-box to the form "I accept the ...".
The value is transferred by the form too, so you can always show that the user has agreed.

Comment: I'm thinking if you really realize the sign-in by extension `forms`, or if you use the dialog of the frontend-login extension `felogin`.